# Ubuntu installation problem

Tags: installation, wubi

I am new to ubuntu and may not quite understand the installation processes. I have 2 hard drives on my computer. A normal IDE **C:/**(50GB) and SATA **E:/**(about 460GB). I have formated my SATA drive in order to install ubuntu as my next operating system. I used an (wubi) installer run from a USB. When it starts installing it works to about a half way and then pops up an error message saying:

> "Could not retrieve the required disk image files
>
> For more information, please see the log file:
>   c:/docume~1/admini~1/locals~1/temp/wubi-12.10-rev273.log!"

Please help, I'd really like to have ubuntu on my old computer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu. Similar questions were asked before by other persons. Take a look at [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/198279/how-to-fix-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-image-files-error), [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170105/wubi-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-image), [3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224558/could-not-retrieve-required-disk-image-file-ubuntu-12-04-1) and [4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254156/how-to-install-with-wubi-when-it-says-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-imag) and certify that your question was not answered.

Comment: If you don't find your answer, consider editing this question, as it doesn't make sense. Wubi is used from within Windows and installs directly to the Windows partition (you don't need to repartition, Ubuntu is stored as a file in Windows). Please clarify how you installed.

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to re-install my windows XP and this time the installer had no problems at all. May have been something with internet connection like Victor Hugo quoted under nr. 4

Answer (score 0):

try live , not from wubi .
first download , unetbootin . then open it and follow the instraction it says.
then open your boot menu and select boot from USB . then restart your PC :)